# Oracle Insert Trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert

I want to insert rows in the table sancion with a trigger but it remains empty after the inserts.

The first referenced table:

```
CREATE TABLE OBSERVACION(

         carretera_foto VARCHAR2(5),
    pto_km_radar    NUMBER(3,0),
    sentido_radar   VARCHAR2(3),
    fecha_foto  VARCHAR2(10),
    hora_foto   TIMESTAMP(6),
    velocidad_foto  NUMBER(3,0),
         limit_vel_radar NUMBER(3,0),
    coche   VARCHAR2(7),
    CONSTRAINT observacion_pk PRIMARY KEY(fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche),
    CONSTRAINT observacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (carretera_foto,pto_km_radar, sentido_radar) REFERENCES Radar (carretera_foto, pto_km_radar, sentido_radar),
    CONSTRAINT observacion_matricula_fk FOREIGN KEY(coche) REFERENCES Vehiculo (matricula) ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

The insert:

```
`INSERT INTO OBSERVACION(carretera_foto, pto_km_radar, sentido_radar, fecha_foto, hora_foto, velocidad_foto,limit_vel_radar, coche)
SELECT distinct carretera_foto, pto_km_radar, sentido_radar, TO_DATE(fecha_foto, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), hora_foto, velocidad_foto, limit_vel_radar, matricula 
 FROM gotcha;`
```

The other table (i want the trigger to insert here):

```
    CREATE TABLE SANCION(
importe NUMBER(3,0),
 fecha_foto VARCHAR2(10),
 hora_foto TIMESTAMP(6),
 coche  VARCHAR2(7),
 tipo VARCHAR2(5),
 NIFdueno VARCHAR2(35),
 CONSTRAINT sancion_pk PRIMARY KEY(fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche, tipo),
 CONSTRAINT sancion_duenio_fk FOREIGN KEY (NIFdueno) REFERENCES Persona (NIFpersona),
 CONSTRAINT sancion_observacion_fk FOREIGN KEY (fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche) REFERENCES Observacion (fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche)
 );
```

The trigger:

```
   CREATE TRIGGER VELOCIDAD
AFTER INSERT ON OBSERVACION FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN(NEW.velocidad_foto > NEW.limit_vel_radar)
    DECLARE
    importe_multa NUMBER(3,0);
    BEGIN
    importe_multa =(:NEW.velocidad_foto - :NEW.limit_vel_radar)*10;
    INSERT INTO SANCION(importe, fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche, tipo)
    VALUES
    (importe_multa, :NEW.fecha_foto, :NEW.hora_foto, :NEW.coche, '1');
    END;
```

The gotcha table:

```
CREATE TABLE gotcha (
    matricula   VARCHAR2(7),
    VIN         VARCHAR2(17),
    marca       VARCHAR2(10),
    modelo      VARCHAR2(12),
    potencia    VARCHAR2(6),
    color       VARCHAR2(25),
    fecha_matricula VARCHAR2(10),
    fecha_ITV   VARCHAR2(10),
    nombre_dueno    VARCHAR2(35),
    apell_1_dueno   VARCHAR2(15),
    apell_2_dueno   VARCHAR2(15),
    direcc_dueno    VARCHAR2(42),
    ciudad_dueno    VARCHAR2(35),
    tlf_dueno   VARCHAR2(9),
    email_dueno VARCHAR2(50),
    cumple_dueno    VARCHAR2(10),
    NIF_dueno   VARCHAR2(9),    
    nombre_condtr   VARCHAR2(35),
    apell_1_condtr  VARCHAR2(15),
    apell_2_condtr  VARCHAR2(15),
    direcc_condtr   VARCHAR2(42),
    ciudad_condtr   VARCHAR2(35),
    tlf_condtr  VARCHAR2(9),
    email_condtr    VARCHAR2(50),
    cumple_condtr   VARCHAR2(10),
    NIF_condtr  VARCHAR2(9),
    carnet_condtr   VARCHAR2(3),    
    fecha_carnet    VARCHAR2(10),
    edad_condtr NUMBER(2,0),
    carretera_foto  VARCHAR2(5),
    limit_vel_ctera NUMBER(3,0),
    pto_km_radar    NUMBER(3,0),
    sentido_radar   VARCHAR2(3),
    limit_vel_radar NUMBER(3,0),
    fecha_foto  VARCHAR2(10),
    hora_foto   VARCHAR2(12),
    velocidad_foto  NUMBER(3,0)
    );
```

Please help.

Comment: You're inserting into `OBSERVACION` but we have no idea what is in the `GOTCHA` table.  And we have no idea whether any of the rows being inserted meet the `WHEN` condition declared in the trigger.

Comment: The format of the Gotcha table is this one. Also the condition in the WHEN meets around 25.000 times.

Comment: @NNausikaa - Post a test case we can see and run on our machines.  An Oracle trigger will fire if the `WHEN` condition is met.  Unless you're omitting the fact that there were exceptions or you're forgetting to commit or something else that you're not mentioning, the trigger will fire and a row will be inserted in `SANCION`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your trigger won't compile as it is because you're using `=` instead of `:=` for assignment. When you create the trigger it should say that it has compiled with errors, and if you do `show errors` or `show errors trigger velocidad` it will tell you what is wrong. It should be:

```
CREATE TRIGGER VELOCIDAD
AFTER INSERT ON OBSERVACION FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW.velocidad_foto > NEW.limit_vel_radar)
DECLARE
    importe_multa NUMBER(3,0);
BEGIN
    importe_multa := (:NEW.velocidad_foto - :NEW.limit_vel_radar)*10;
    INSERT INTO SANCION(importe, fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche, tipo)
    VALUES
    (importe_multa, :NEW.fecha_foto, :NEW.hora_foto, :NEW.coche, '1');
END;
/
```

You don't really need the assignment though, you can do the calculation directly in the insert:

```
CREATE TRIGGER VELOCIDAD
AFTER INSERT ON OBSERVACION FOR EACH ROW
WHEN NEW.velocidad_foto > NEW.limit_vel_radar
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO SANCION(importe, fecha_foto, hora_foto, coche, tipo)
    VALUES ((:NEW.velocidad_foto - :NEW.limit_vel_radar)*10,
        :NEW.fecha_foto, :NEW.hora_foto, :NEW.coche, '1');
END;
/
```